# Android - Shinobi charts

Tags: android, android-fragments, background, shinobi

I'm implementing a bar graph using Shinobi library in android. I have two questions 
1.How do I make the charts background transparent?
2.How do I redraw the graph to change the graph values after clicking a button after clicking a button?

Answer (score 0):

ShinobiCharts for Android has several methods which will allow you to set the transparency of the chart background.

These methods are contained in the chart's style object which you first obtain using:

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiChartsAndroid/1.6.0/Premium/Normal/apidocs/docs/reference/com/shinobicontrols/charts/ShinobiChart.html#getStyle()

With the style object in hand, you can access the relevant methods:

Firstly, you can change the background colour of the overall chart. This will affect the background area of items outside of the plot area and axes, such as the chart title and legend:

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiChartsAndroid/1.6.0/Premium/Normal/apidocs/docs/reference/com/shinobicontrols/charts/ChartStyle.html#setBackgroundColor(int)

You can also modify the background colour of the chart canvas, which which is the area taken up by the plot area and the axes (if you have no chart title or legend then the chart and chart canvas will be of equal size):

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiChartsAndroid/1.6.0/Premium/Normal/apidocs/docs/reference/com/shinobicontrols/charts/ChartStyle.html#setCanvasBackgroundColor(int)

Finally, you can change the background colour of the plot area - which is the area where the data is visualised:

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiChartsAndroid/1.6.0/Premium/Normal/apidocs/docs/reference/com/shinobicontrols/charts/ChartStyle.html#setPlotAreaBackgroundColor(int)

You can of course provide a transparent colour to any of these methods.

In order to request a redraw of the chart you should use the following method:

http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiChartsAndroid/1.6.0/Premium/Normal/apidocs/docs/reference/com/shinobicontrols/charts/ShinobiChart.html#redrawChart()

I hope this helps, thanks,

Kai

Disclaimer: I work for ShinobiControls.

edit - if you want to display values on top of the bars and customise their color, you should take a look at our Annotations functionality (this is a premium feature): http://www.shinobicontrols.com/docs/ShinobiControls/ShinobiChartsAndroid/1.6.0/Premium/Normal/user-guide/how-to-add-annotations.html

Hope this helps, 
Kai.

Comment: thank you making the background transparent worked perfectly. For drawing the graph with new data after clicking on the button I removed the previous series and added the new series, it worked

Comment: is it possible to display values on top of the bars and customise their color?